# LAMP Server refuses to send email with PHP mail() function

Tags: php, email, lamp

I setup my LAMP server on a Raspberry-pi

Everything seems to run fine EXCEPT when I get to my mail() function in PHP

I cant seem to figure out why its not working. I think it has to do with the server setup itself. I thought maybe also it could be the router blocking outgoing traffic from the server but I am almost 100% sure its the LAMP server itself.

```
<?php
 $to = "myemail@myemail.com";
 $subject = $_POST['sub'];
 $body = $_POST['body'];

     mail($to, "Website Contact Request:".$subject, $body);

     $ret = $_POST['email'];
     if($ret!=null){
       mail($ret,"Anthony Russell.Info Auto-Reply","Thank you for your email, I will be in touch soon!");
      }

      header( 'LOCATION:index.php' ) ;
 ?>
```

### UPDATE

I just followed this tutorial with no success http://www.sitepoint.com/advanced-email-php/

Comment: I think you need to add the fourth argument, `$headers` to your `mail()` function.  You should put at least a `From: <someone@example.com>` header in.  Also, you can put that function in an `if/else` statement to test the return value.  If it returns `true` then PHP at least handed the mail off to the local MTA.

Comment: @Crackertastic so something I should add is this is a copy and paste from a site I had hosted on GoDaddy. I literally just moved the page from Godaddy to my home server. It worked fine on godaddy

Comment: have you setup sendmail ?

Comment: @JoniSalmi no clue what that is so I am guessing not. Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: Honestly it could be a number of things (including server setup as you said), but that was just something I noticed off the top of my head. Each mail server is different when it comes to handling email.  The mail you are sending could be flagged as spam, it could be in a slow queue on the server side, etc.  Again though, put it inside an `if()` and see if you get a `true` out of it.  At least then you know PHP did it's part and handed it off to the MTA to (hopefully) get delivered.  I had a similar problem just a couple days ago and it was because the spam filter on the receiving server.

Comment: Check your smtp server. Sendmail is an example of smtp server.